# ggplotly reactive graph is showing up on viewer panel in RStudio but not in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

My interactive ggplot won't show up on my shiny app but will show up in RStudio and react to the changes from the shiny application. It was fine until I made the graph interactive and not sure why it has changed.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$selected_nation <- renderText({ 
paste("You have selected", input$Nationality)
})

output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    ngo <-
      ngo %>%
      filter(Victim.Nationality == input$Nationality,
             Victim.Gender == input$genderInput
      )

p = ggplot(ngo, aes(x = Victim.Age, fill = Trafficking.Type)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack")
ggplotly(p)
})
```

The graph to work within the shiny app.

Comment: replace `renderPlot` with `renderPlotly`

Comment: Tried that didn't work and then stops graph from updating from changes fro selectInput

Comment: do you use `plotlyOutput` in the UI ? Not easy to help without the full code...

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent that worked, thank you!! Still getting to grips with R and shiny

Comment: You should write Stephane Laurent's solution as an answer, so that people can see that this problem is solved